Fundamental groups of spherical space forms
Is it true that every countable group has a spherical space form as its classifying space? My reasoning of this counter-intuitive conjecture is as follows ($\mathbb{E}^n$ denotes the $n$-dimensional real Hilbert space below):
Let $G$ be a countable group. My goal is to construct a free and properly discontinuous isometric action of $G$ on the unit sphere $\mathbb{S}^{\omega}$ of the seperable Hilbert space $\mathbb{E}^{\omega}$. Since $\mathbb{S}^{\omega}$ is contractible and has constant sectional curvature $1$, the quotient space is a model of $K(G,1)$ and also a spherical space form.
Case $1$: $G$ is the fundamental group of an $(n-1)$-dimensional spherical space form for some finite $n$. Then $G$ acts isometrically on $\mathbb{E}^n$ as a subgroup of $O(n)$. Regard $\mathbb{E}^{\omega}$ as the countable $l^2$-direct sum of $\mathbb{E}^n$ and we have $\mathbb{S}^{\omega} \cong \{ (v_1,v_2,\cdots) \mid v_i \in \mathbb{E}^n, \sum_{i=1}^{+\infty} \lVert v_i \rVert^2 = 1 \}$. The action $g.(v_1,v_2,\cdots) = (g.v_1,g.v_2,\cdots)$ achieves the goal.
Case $2$: $G$ is torsion-free. Enumerate an orthonormal frame of $\mathbb{E}^{\omega}$ by elements of $G$ and we have $\mathbb{S}^{\omega} \cong \{ (v_{h_1},v_{h_2},\cdots) \mid v_h \in \mathbb{E}^1, \sum_{h \in G} \lVert v_h \rVert^2 = 1 \}$. The action $g.(v_{h_1},v_{h_2},\cdots) = (v_{g^{-1}h_1},v_{g^{-1}h_2},\cdots)$ achieves the goal.
Case $3$: $G$ is a direct product of case $1$ and case $2$. Suppose $G = A \times B$ where $A$ belongs to case $1$ and $B$ belongs to case $2$. Regard $\mathbb{E}^{\omega}$ as the countable $l^2$-direct sum of $\mathbb{E}^n$ enumerated by elements of $G$ and we have $\mathbb{S}^{\omega} \cong \{ (v_{h_1},v_{h_2},\cdots) \mid v_h \in \mathbb{E}^n, \sum_{h \in G} \lVert v_h \rVert^2 = 1 \}$. The action $(a,b).(v_{h_1},v_{h_2},\cdots) = (a.v_{b^{-1}h_1},a.v_{b^{-1}h_2},\cdots)$ achieves the goal.
(The freeness and proper continuity of the aforementioned actions are not trivial, but the proof is somewhat technical so I omit it here.)
Note that $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^2$ (with $p \ge 3$ prime) is not included above. However, while no action of $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^2$ on finite-dimensional spheres can be free, situation is different for $\mathbb{S}^{\omega}$ since $\mathbb{S}^{\omega} \times \mathbb{S}^{\omega} \cong \mathbb{S}^{\omega}$ and the left hand side admits a lens-space-like free $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^2$ action. It's not clear to me whether constant curvature $1$ plays a role.

In the paper described below, it is proved that if $G$ is a finite group with a nonabelian composition factor not isomorphic to $A_5$ or $A_6$, then for any list of finite-dimensional unitary representations $V_1,\dotsc,V_n$, the action of $G$ on $S(V_1)\times\dotsb\times S(V_n)$ is not free.  Any infinite dimensional unitary representation will decompose into isotypical pieces isomorphic to $\ell^2\otimes S$ for some finite-dimensional simple representation $S$, and it follows that allowing infinite dimensional representations does not change the conclusion.
@article {MR1161304,
    AUTHOR = {Ray, Urmie},
     TITLE = {Free linear actions of finite groups on products of spheres},
   JOURNAL = {J. Algebra},
  FJOURNAL = {Journal of Algebra},
    VOLUME = {147},
      YEAR = {1992},
    NUMBER = {2},
     PAGES = {456--490},
      ISSN = {0021-8693,1090-266X},
   MRCLASS = {20C15 (57S25)},
  MRNUMBER = {1161304},
MRREVIEWER = {David\ Benson},
       DOI = {10.1016/0021-8693(92)90216-9},
       URL = {https://doi.org/10.1016/0021-8693(92)90216-9},
}


Oh, I totally forgot that a unitary representation of a compact Lie group on a Hilbert space has a finite-dimensional irreducible sub-representation!
